# dcc32 Error Unit1.pas(284): E2010 Incompatible types: 'TNavigateBtn' and 'TNavigateButton'

Tags: delphi, delphi-10.2-tokyo

I want to replace a `TDBNavigator` with a button.

I did :

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  DBNavigator2.BtnClick(nbNext);
end;
```

but I got an error :

> [dcc32 Error] Unit1.pas(284): E2010 Incompatible types: 'TNavigateBtn' and 'TNavigateButton'

Please, could anyone tell me how to fix this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the full type name **TNavigateBtn.nbNext**, for example:

```
DBNavigator2.BtnClick(TNavigateBtn.nbNext);
```

That happens most probably because you have **Data.Bind.Controls** unit in your uses clause. This unit declares the same named **nbNext** member as a part of the **TNavigateButton** enumeration.

Comment: thank you very much
it is possible to make this button disable when he come to the end of recod ? like the button of dbnavigator?

Comment: You're welcome! What you mean by end of record? If you mean the end of a dataset (last record), then it should already happen..

Comment: @MohammedBouhlal that is a new question  and needs to be posted separately. This question has been answered as asked.

Comment: @Victoria DBNavigator disables its own buttons automatically, but a user's own button would have to be disabled manually.